# export schema using oracle expdp

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-dump

I use [this tutorial](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g) to export one schema into some directory. I have created a directory and granted the user as follows:

> CREATE DIRECTORY foo as '/data';
>
> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY foo TO Scott;

This works fine.Now when I try to export some schema as follow:

> EXPDP SCOTT7TIGER@mysip schemas=schema_to_be_exported directory=dbdir
> dumpfile=exp.dmp logfile=log.log

it prints the following error to me:

```
ORA-31631: privileges are required
ORA-39109: unprivileged users my not poerate upon other users' schemas.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `EXP_FULL_DATABASE` to export from other schemas and `IMP_FULL_DATABASE` to import into other schemas (this includes SCHEMA_REMAP).